# Bandha/Mudra that stimulates pleasure centre

Tags: yoga, pranayama, mudra, hatha-yoga

What are the specific mudras/bandhas in Hatha Yoga that stimulate/ enhance the pleasure centres. Like, for example, I think the Mula Bandha is close to stimulating the pleasure centre of the genital organ. Any other such examples? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: There are actually orgasm-giving meditations, I don't know if they are helpful or not. However, they are not much recommended as they could arouse Kundalini and we don't definitely want that. Another good one I remember is *Vajroli* in hatha yoga and some kama-based tantra techniques from VBT, very good ones as they benefit spiritually as well.

Comment: although hatha yoga is a part of indian cultural tradition, it is not a part of the hindu religion per se.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda yes, but since there is no yoga/pranayama stackexchange, and in addition, several yoga/pranayama questions are asked, plus the tags themselves being present makes my question valid for the site. By the way, the principle texts of hatha yoga-Hatha Yoga Pradipika, Gheranda and Siva Samhita are very much part of tantra, which is essentially a Hindu part